# ComboBox and Entity Framework, How do I get the ID? (WPF-MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, combobox, entity

How do I get the Id of the selected language in the ViewModel.AddNewMovie()? 
This is my first try. It's bad, because it's the Index, and isn't the Id.

**View:**

```
...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesCollection}" 
SelectedIndex="{Binding NewMovieLanguage}"
DisplayMemberPath="L_Name" SelectedValuePath="L_Id"/>
...
```

**ViewModel:**

```
...

public ObservableCollection<Languages> LanguagesCollection { get; private set; }
public ObservableCollection<Movies> MoviesCollection{ get; private set; }

...

_Entities = new MyAppEntities();
LanguagesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Languages>(_Entities.Languages);
MoviesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Movies>(_Entities.Movies.Include("Languages"));

...

private void AddNewMovie()
{
        OnPropertyChanged("NewMovieTitle");
        OnPropertyChanged("NewMovieLanguage");
    try
    {
        Movies NewMovie = new Movies 
        {
            M_Title = NewMovieTitle,
            M_Language_Id = Convert.ToInt32(NewMovieLanguage)+1,
        };

        _Entities.AddToMovies(NewMovie);
        MoviesCollection.Add(NewMovie);
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Entity DataModel:**

**Movies** (table)

M_Id *Int32*

M_Title *String*

M_Language_Id *Int32 fk*

**Languages** (table)

L_Id *Int32*

L_Name *String*

**-- Data --**

**Languages**

1 English

2 German

3 French

4 Spanish

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the solution is:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesCollection}" 
SelectedValue="{Binding NewMovieLanguage}"
DisplayMemberPath="L_Name" SelectedValuePath="L_Id"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

please change same as:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguagesCollection}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding NewMovieLanguage}"
DisplayMemberPath="L_Name" SelectedValuePath="L_Id"/>
```